# Windows Powershell: eval a series of commands in active shell

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have a series of commands:

```
# foo.ps1
do-this
do-that 
do-something-totally-different
etc.
```

Next, I want to stop having to write these out in the active shell (because it modifies my shell environment), so in bash I would just write:

```
cat foo.ps1 | xargs -I arg eval arg
```

Or something along those lines.

How do I achieve the same effect with windows powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a script file in the current scope rather than a new scope, use *dot-sourcing*:

```
. .\foo.ps1
```

Alternatively, you can use `Invoke-Expression`, PowerShell's `eval` equivalent, which should be exactly the same as typing out the commands yourself at the prompt:

```
Get-Content .\foo.ps1 -Raw | Invoke-Expression
```

Or more concisely:

```
gc .\foo.ps1 -raw | iex
```